# Dynamic JS calendar events positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I have a created a calendar with js, css and html.
I have managed to add one day events and longer lasting events - all seems fine when events are not overlapping, but when events are overlapping, the overlapping part is fine, but if there are two events one from 10-18 and another from 16-22, then days 16-18 are fine and the two events are not on top of each other but days 18-22 are not affected the same way days 16-18 are.

```js
const holidayInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.holidayInputs');

const holidays = [];

holidayInputs.forEach(input => {
  const value = input.value;

  const [date, name] = value.split('.');

  holidays.push({ hdate: date, holiday: name });
});

const events = [
  {
    title: "As puhkab",
    startDate: "03-12-2024",
    endDate: "03-20-2024",
  },
  {
    title: "Ak puhkab",
    startDate: "03-04-2024",
    endDate: "03-14-2024",
  },
  {
    title: "AC puhkab",
    startDate: "03-26-2024",
    endDate: "03-31-2024",
  }
  // Add more events as needed
];
const calendar = document.querySelector("#calendar");
const monthBanner = document.querySelector("#month");
let navigation = 0;
const weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

function loadCalendar() {
  const dt = new Date();

  if (navigation != 0) {
    dt.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + navigation);
  }
  const day = dt.getDate();
  const month = dt.getMonth();
  const year = dt.getFullYear();
  monthBanner.innerText = `${dt.toLocaleDateString("en-us", {
    month: "long",
  })} ${year}`;
  calendar.innerHTML = "";
  const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
  const firstDayofMonth = new Date(year, month, 1);
  const dateText = firstDayofMonth.toLocaleDateString("en-us", {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
  });

  const dayString = dateText.split(", ")[0];
  const emptyDays = weekdays.indexOf(dayString);

  const shownEventsDates = new Set();

  for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth + emptyDays; i++) {
    const dayBox = document.createElement("div");
    dayBox.classList.add("day");

    // Calculate the index of the current day
    const currentIndex = i - emptyDays; //current day date index (matched w date)

    // Calculate the date of the current day
    const currentDate = new Date(year, month, currentIndex); // current date

    // Get the day of the week (0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, etc.)
    const dayOfWeek = (currentDate.getDay() + 6) % 7;

    if (currentIndex > 0 && currentIndex <= daysInMonth) {
      dayBox.innerText = currentIndex;

      // Adjust for the correct placement of the first day of the month
      if (currentIndex === 1) {
        const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 1);
        const firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfMonth.getDay();
        const offset = firstDayOfWeek - 1; // Adjust for starting day being Monday
        if (offset < 0) {
          dayBox.style.gridColumnStart = 7; // Adjust for Sunday
        } else {
          dayBox.style.gridColumnStart = offset + 1;
        }
      }

      const monthVal = month + 1 < 10 ? "0" + (month + 1) : month + 1;
      const dateVal = currentIndex < 10 ? "0" + currentIndex : currentIndex;
      const dateText = `${dateVal}-${monthVal}-${year}`;

      const holidayOfTheDay = holidays.find((e) => e.hdate == dateText);

      if (i - emptyDays === day && navigation == 0) {
        dayBox.id = "currentDay";
      }
      // Push holidays into the calendar - can be recreated with birthdays
      if (holidayOfTheDay) {
        const eventDiv = document.createElement("div");
        eventDiv.classList.add("event");
        eventDiv.classList.add("holiday");
        eventDiv.innerText = holidayOfTheDay.holiday;
        dayBox.appendChild(eventDiv);

        dayBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
          showModal(dateText);
        });
      }

      // Check if there are events for this day and it hasn't been shown already
      const eventsForDay = events.filter(event => {
        const eventStartDate = new Date(event.startDate);
        const eventEndDate = new Date(event.endDate);

        const isWithinMonth = eventStartDate.getMonth() == month || eventEndDate.getMonth() == month;
        const isWithinEventRange = currentDate >= eventStartDate && currentDate <= eventEndDate;

        return isWithinMonth && isWithinEventRange && !shownEventsDates.has(dateText);
      });
      
      if (eventsForDay.length > 0) {
        // Create a container for day events
        const dayEventContainer = document.createElement("div");
        dayEventContainer.classList.add("day-events");
        dayBox.appendChild(dayEventContainer);

        // Sort events by start time
        eventsForDay.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.startDate) - new Date(b.startDate));

        // Keep track of processed events within each week
        const processedEventsByWeek = new Map();

        eventsForDay.forEach((event, index) => {
          // Get event Start and end dates
          const eventStart = new Date(event.startDate);
          const eventEnd = new Date(event.endDate);

          let marginTop = 0;
          let overlappingEvents = [];
          const weekNumber = Math.floor((currentDate.getDate() - 1 + emptyDays) / 7);

          if (!processedEventsByWeek.has(weekNumber)) {
            processedEventsByWeek.set(weekNumber, new Set());
          }

          for (let week = 0; week <= weekNumber; week++) {
            if (processedEventsByWeek.has(week)) {
              for (const processedEvent of processedEventsByWeek.get(week)) {
                const processedEventStart = new Date(processedEvent.startDate);
                const processedEventEnd = new Date(processedEvent.endDate);

                // Check for overlap
                if (eventStart < processedEventEnd && eventEnd > processedEventStart) {
                  overlappingEvents.push(processedEvent);
                }
              }
            }
          }

          // Calculate maximum marginTop for the entire duration of the event
          if (overlappingEvents.length > 0) {
            marginTop = overlappingEvents.length * 20;
          }


          /*// Ensure there's an entry for this week
          if (!processedEventsByWeek.has(weekNumber)) {
            processedEventsByWeek.set(weekNumber, new Set());
          }

          // Check if the event overlaps with any previously processed event in this week
          let marginTop = 0;
          for (const processedEvent of processedEventsByWeek.get(weekNumber)) {
            const processedEventEnd = new Date(processedEvent.endDate);
            // If there's an overlap, adjust marginTop and break
            if ( eventStart <= processedEventEnd ) {
              marginTop += 20; // Adjust marginTop to prevent overlap
            }
          }*/

          // Add this event to the set of processed events for this week
          processedEventsByWeek.get(weekNumber).add(event);

          const weekWidth = 770; // Total width of the week in pixels
          const daysInWeek = weekdays.length;
          const dayWidth = weekWidth / daysInWeek; // Calculate the width of each day within the week

          const eventDiv = document.createElement("div");
          eventDiv.classList.add("event");
          eventDiv.classList.add("event-span");
          if (eventStart.getDate() == currentDate.getDate() || dayOfWeek == 0) {
            eventDiv.innerText = event.title;
          }

          // Apply marginTop if necessary
          if (marginTop > 0) {
            eventDiv.style.marginTop = `${marginTop}px`;
          }

          // Set the right offset for event start
          let eventStartOffset = Math.max(0, eventStart.getDay() * dayWidth);

          const dayEventDiv = document.createElement("div");
          dayEventDiv.classList.add("day-event");
          dayEventDiv.style.left = eventStartOffset + "px"
          if (eventEnd.getDate() == currentDate.getDate() || dayOfWeek == 6) {
            dayEventDiv.style.width = 95 + "px";
          } else {
            dayEventDiv.style.width = dayWidth + "px";
          }

          eventDiv.appendChild(dayEventDiv);
          dayEventContainer.appendChild(eventDiv);
          
          shownEventsDates.add(dateText); // Record that this event has been shown
        });

        dayBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
          showModal(dateText);
        });
      }
    } else {
      dayBox.classList.add("plain");
    }
    calendar.append(dayBox);
  }
}

function buttons() {
  const btnBack = document.querySelector("#btnBack");
  const btnNext = document.querySelector("#btnNext");

  btnBack.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navigation--;
    loadCalendar();
  });
  btnNext.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navigation++;
    loadCalendar();
  });
}

const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
const modalClose = document.querySelector(".modal-close");

function showModal(dateText) {
  clicked = dateText;
  modal.style.display = "flex";

  // modaali sisu loogika :D
  
  modalClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  });
}

buttons();
loadCalendar();
```

```css
.container {
    width: 770px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-table;
}
.header {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.header #month {
    color: #1562CE;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white;
}
.header button {
    background-color: #1562CE;
}
.weekdays {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #E8F2FE;;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #0A253C;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.weekdays div {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#calendar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
}
.day:hover {
    background-color: #C2D8F6;
    color: #03a9f4;
}
.day.plain:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
#currentDay {
    background-color: #a3c5f5;
    color: #fff;
}
.day-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.day {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #cbd4c2;
    color: #7f8fa6;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.day-events {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 39px;
}
.day-event {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.event {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 11px;
    max-height: 18px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
}
.event.event-span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -9px;
    min-height: 18px;
}
.event.event-span-one {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.event.holiday {
    background-color: #E0593E;
    color: white;
    position: initial;
    max-width: 87px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.plain {
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    left: 795px;
    width: 420px;
    height: 51vh;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#modal .modal-close {
    background-color: #E0593E;
    height: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div id="month"></div>
            <div>
                <button id="btnBack"><span class="icon-Arrow-Left"></span></button>
                <button id="btnNext"><span class="icon-Arrow-Right"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="weekdays">
            <div>Mon</div>
            <div>Tue</div>
            <div>Wed</div>
            <div>Thu</div>
            <div>Fri</div>
            <div>Sat</div>
            <div>Sun</div>
        </div>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
        <div id="modal">
            <button class="modal-close"><i class="icon-Close"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried changing the logic how the margin top is given, but i cannot think of a good way for this to be implemented on the whole event duration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.